# How to clear interval in WebSocket when some condition is met outside the scope?

Tags: javascript, node.js, websocket, ws

I have a simple WebSocket server like this:

```js
wss.on('connection', ws => {
  console.log('user is connected to the server')
  const t = setInterval(() => {
    ++count
    ws.send(count)
  }, 2000);
})
```

and I have a code down the page like

```js
setInterval(() => {
  ++flag
}, 2000);
```

`flag` being `let flag = 1.`
I'd like to clear the first interval when `flag` hits a certain number like 10.
How do I achieve that?

Comment: Which interval?  You have two.

Comment: @Taplar First interval marked as const t.

Comment: `const t` is scoped too low.  Nothing outside of that arrow function can reference it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to define `t` outside of your function to extend the scope

```
let t;
wss.on('connection', ws => {
  console.log('user is connected to the server')
  t = setInterval(() => {
    ++count
    ws.send(count)
  }, 2000);
})
```

and then clear it when flag is ok

```
let flag = 1;
setInterval(() => {
  ++flag;
  if(flag===10)
    clearInterval(t);
}, 2000);
```

And also, I advise you to use more expressing name than just `t`.

Maybe, you also want to clear the second timer

```
let flag = 1;
let secondTimer = setInterval(() => {
  ++flag;
  if(flag===10) {
    clearInterval(t);
    clearInterval(secondTimer);
  }
}, 2000);
```

NB : not tested !